# Use another repository as service in GitHub Actions workflow

Tags: java, github, github-actions

So, I am currently working on a project that consists of different repositories/services that I want to test using JUnit in Github Actions workflow. Since I have multiple repos that depend on ach other, I would like to test them in one workflow instance so they can connect to each other.

I have:

- 1. Rest api authorization service
- 2. Rest api service that uses the authorization service

I would like to run the authorization service as on of the "services" in the 2nd service workflow so the 2nd service can connect to it. Is it possible?

My current workflow in the 2nd service:

```
on: [push]
env:
  NODE_NAME: '1'
  MYSQL_DATABASE: 'test'
  MYSQL_USER: 'test'
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'test'


jobs:
  test_node:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 5
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'adopt'
      - name: Shutdown default MySQL
        run: sudo service mysql stop
      - name: Setup MySQL
        uses: mirromutth/mysql-action@v1.1
        with:
          mysql database: 'test'
          mysql user: 'test'
          mysql password: 'test'
          mysql port: 3306
      - name: Grant gradlew permissions
        run: chmod +x gradlew
      - name: Gradle Build
        run: ./gradlew :api-node:build -x test
      - name: Gradle Test
        run: ./gradlew :api-node:test
      - name: JUnit Report Action
        uses: mikepenz/action-junit-report@v3.7.1
        if: always()
        with:
          report_paths: '**/build/test-results/test/TEST-*.xml'
```

I created the workflow and I realized that I can only start public docker images as services, so I would like to use the repository as service without the need of publishing it to docker repository.

Thank you